# Add spacebar in WP List Table Search

Tags: plugins

I would like to add spacebar %20 or + on the redirect URL in the search, how can I do that with the add_query_arg?

```
function bulk_search() {
    $redirect_to = add_query_arg( array( 's' => $_POST['s'] ), $_POST['_wp_http_referer']);
    wp_redirect( $redirect_to );
    exit();
}
```

With the function above, if in the search box I keyed in "Hello World" it would return the search with **&s=helloworld** on the URL instead of **&s=hello+world**

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
function bulk_search() {
    $redirect_to = add_query_arg( array( 's' => urlencode($_POST['s']) ), $_POST['_wp_http_referer']);
    wp_redirect( $redirect_to );
    exit();
}
```

Realised by adding urlencode() function would do.